# Why is my frame printing not working in my custom roguelike?

Tags: python

I'm working on a roguelike game, and I tried printing the frames:

```
i = 0
def lv1():
while i == 0:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
    if x == 0:
        if y == 0:
            print("@ - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            move = input("")
            if move == "d":
                x = 1
    elif x == 1:
        if y == 0:
            print("- @ - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
            print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
```

but for some reason, this idea won't work!
Is there something wrong with the loop?

I tried making a loop to repeat the process,
but the frames just stay stuck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your intended output? And what does not exactly work? Also check if the python indentations are properly followed

Comment: although you set `x=1`, `x` is reset to 0 in every loop, so you need to move `x` out of while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 0
def lv1():
    ## check here , wrong indentation 
    while i == 0:
        x = 0
        y = 0
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        if x == 0:
            if y == 0:
                print("@ - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                move = input("")
                if move == "d":
                    x = 1
        elif x == 1:
            if y == 0:
                print("- @ - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")

lv1() #invoke the function
```

Your indentation is not correct and also forgot to invoke the function `lv1()` at the end of program.

Comment: I did that in the actual project,

Comment: but stackoverflow's code thing is confusing so I accidentally idented that the wrong way. I did call the function in my project, but it does not work!

Comment: WAIT I FOUND OUT!!!
It resets the variables each time the function is called!!